# One conch twisted connection for sftp and cdm

Tags: twisted, sftp

please tell me whether it is possible to use one SSHConnection to sftp, execute commands, and for port forwarding?
And allow me one question - is it possible to transfer multiple files over one SSHConnection connection?

Maybe there are examples.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  For example, you can use [`SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.endpoints.SSHCommandClientEndpoint.html#existingConnection) to create an `SSHCommandClientEndpoint` to run commands on an existing connection rather than establishing a new one.